# Using retina display Vs Binary size

Tags: ios4, retina-display

I'm currently updating my app's images to have a nice display on iphone4 with retina display. Everything works well and I'm quite happy with it.

However, what concerns me is that increasing binary size... (starting from 2Mb, I reached 4) Did you find a way to have nice images and to keep a decent size for your binaries?

Tips or advices would be welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 MBs more don't matter at all on a 32 GB device. 4 MB is 1/250th of a GB. :) (okay, it'd allow the user to sync a half MP3 less.)

I always delete non-retina apps. They suck and are ugly. If you don't care about uglyness, I'd suggest you quit iPhone development and start Windows Phone development (A)

Comment: ahahaha I do really care about uglyness, that's why i'm making this move!

Comment: In your opinion, size does not matter? (for the app I mean). I was thinking that too big binaries could be repulsive... Maybe i'm wrong.

Comment: Size **could** matter, but in your case, 2 MB, it does not. If it takes about 600 MBs more I'd say OK, but 2 MB is nothing. Note that the images are not saved in the binary itself, but in the bundle (a special type of directory) where the binary is in. The binary loads all images at runtime. They aren't in the binary file itself. Try unzipping a random IPA and right-click and show package contents on the payload. You could also do this with any Mac application.

Answer (score 0):

It's sometimes worth running something like [pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) on your image files. It should result in zero visible difference but often results in far smaller files.

Comment: Xcode already takes care of compressing the PNG. Unzip a random IPA and check the PNGs in it. They are extremely small.

Comment: All I can say is that it seemed to have an effect in my apps.